# Hadoop: split a big image file using a custom input format

Tags: java, hadoop

I am working on big geographic image files with a size greater than a hdfs block. I need to split the images into several strips (with an height of `100px` for instance), then apply some processes on them and finally rebuild the final image.
To do so, I have created a custom input format (inherited from FileInputFormat) and a custom record reader. I am splitting the image in the input format, by defining several FileSplit (corresponding to one strip) which are read in the record reader.

I am not sure my splitting process is optimized because a strip can be accross 2 hdfs blocks, and I don't know how to "send" the split to the best worker (the one where there will be the minimal number of remote reading)

For the moment I am using [`FileInputFormat.getBlockIndex()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html#getBlockIndex%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockLocation%5B%5D,%20long%29) with the split beginning offset in order to get the host of the split.

Do you have any advices to help me to solve this problem?

P.S. I am using the new Hadoop API

Answer (score 1):

Image processing on hadoop using HIPI,
[*Check this out, http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/*][1]

Answer (score 0):

If it is realistic to process an entire image in a single mapper then you may find it simpler to achieve full data locality by making the block size of the image files larger than the size of each image, and get parallelism by processing multiple images at a time.